# How to use Hold on a variable defined as a graph

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, graphs-and-networks

I'm working on doing operations on different graphs and getting their probability node degree distributions using a simple algorithm.

If I have many defined graphs, for example:

```
g=RandomGraph[{5, 6}];
h=RandomGraph[{15, 10}];
```

What "Hold" operation do I want to use in order to get the output of the graph's name? e.g. "g" or "h"

Here Is my code:

```
plotting[g_Graph] := Module[{probs1, purged, r = Range@Max@VertexDegree@g}, 
probs1 = {#, Probability[x == #, x \[Distributed] VertexDegree[g]]} & /@ r;
purged = DeleteCases[probs1, {x_, y_} /; x y == 0];
ListPlot[Log@purged, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{HoldForm[ln P[K]], g}, {HoldForm[ln K], None}}, PlotLabel -> HoldForm[g]]
```

My question is specifically: Inside of PlotLabel, when I use

```
PlotLabel->HoldForm[g]
```

How can I get that to output either "g" or "h" or whatever the inputted graph is?

I've tried all sorts of Hold functions (HoldFirst etc...), and I suspect that I need to use a String-type expression but I haven't been able to narrow it down.

Comment: You need to `SetAttributes[plotting, HoldAll]`.  The rest looks fine, though I didn't test.  Check [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressionsOverview.html), in particular Nonstandard Evaluation.

Comment: @Szabolcs I looked through it and still having trouble. Would I use it inside of module? but don't I want to g to be evaluated in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by @Szabolcs, you just have to use `SetAttributes[plotting, HoldAll]` or even in your case `SetAttributes[plotting, HoldFirst]` (because you have only one argument) when defining your function.
But then, there is a problem to test the header of the function argument, `plotting[g_Graph]` won't never plot anything because as `g` is now by defintion maintained in an unevaluated form, its header is `Symbol` not `Graph`. However there is a workaround for this using the condition `/;`test.

See for example this function :

```
SetAttributes[func, HoldFirst];
func[x_ /; GraphQ[x]] := {Head@x, x, x // OutputForm, HoldForm[x], 
Range@Max@VertexDegree@x}
```

#### Tests :

```
 func[12]
(* as expected returns func[12] because 12 is not a Graph *)
```

and

```
g = RandomGraph[{5, 6}];
func[g]
```

gives

[image]

#### To record the input command :

As you notice, the form `g // OutputForm` which gives `Graph[< 5 >, < 6 >]` is probably more useful than just the name of the variable `g`.
But you can also "record" the exact command which produced the graph with this small universal function for example :

```
SetAttributes[rec, HoldFirst]
rec[input_] := {ToString@HoldForm@input, input}
```

Then

```
g = rec[RandomGraph[{5, 6}]]
```

gives

[image]

`g`is now a list containing the command and the result of the command. You'll have of course to modify your other functions, so they can handle this type of list as their new argument.

Comment: I got here trying to understand the differences between testing pattern `f[g_Graph]` and `f[g_?GraphQ]`. Above different usage syntax, is this the only difference: that `?GraphQ` forces evaluation of the argument to the function that may have `HoldFirst` set? Are there other cases?

Comment: If you meant that I could have used `x_?GraphQ` instead of `x_ /; GraphQ[x]` you are perfectly right, the result would be the same here. I just missed that ! :) Now, I don't know if I understand well your question but : the fundamental difference is that `g_Graph` tests the [type](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecifyingTypesOfExpressionInPatterns.html) or [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html?q=Head) of the `g` expression, and `g_?GraphQ` applies the test [`GraphQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphQ.html?q=GraphQ) to `g` which consists

Comment: in testing the head of the (as you say) evaluated form of g. With the [`PatternTest` or `?`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html?q=PatternTest) you can however actually apply any other test to the g expression (not only test the head).  Concerning the evaluation of a held expression with `?` or using the condition form `/; ` look at the examples of the last section `Possible Issues`.